# How can I post-process my OpenGL physics simulation results to accelerate playback?

Tags: opengl, rendering, playback, compute-shader

I have created a physics simulation of particles falling with gravity and colliding with a floor. The physics time step is very small (10^-6 or 0.000001), so many steps are needed to equate to a second of real time. Compute shader's for physics and a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER is used for immediate rendering per frame at the moment.

I want to be able to view this *AFTER* the physics calculations are completed and play the full animation back at a faster-than-captured rate. For example I should be able to calculate 20 seconds of physics and play this back in real-time.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: If you want to complete all the physics calculations *before* playing it back, then you're going to have to be able to *store* all of the physics calculations. Since you have 10^6 timesteps per second, you are going to need a storage buffer that can hold 2*10^7 timesteps to store 20 seconds of data. Even if one timestep's worth of data is only 512 bytes, 20 seconds of data at that resolution will consume 9.5 GiB.

Comment: Capture a video of the graphical output using [OBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Broadcaster_Software)?

Comment: Thank you Nicol. Are you aware of any 'temporary' cache or memory store accessible within OpenGL that avoids me having to 'dump' the data locally and simply retrieve the results on the fly? Would this be possble with an c++ array structure or similar? My original plan was to create an app that can render real-time, but due to the small time steps and number of particles needed, I am having to reconsider this and think about solving separately and viewing in a classic physics solver and post-process style manner...

Comment: In addition my previous comment, I would ideally like to have the option of being able to apply shaders to the renders from the results data i.e. post-processing filters